# How to update_batch or just update all rows in my table

Tags: php, codeigniter

my table updates all the rows, using only the last row data not the data in each rows.

this is my model

```
public function update3($dtr_id)
    {   
        // $lateDdc_total_rate = $_POST['lateDdc_total_rate'];

        if (is_array($dtr_id)) 
        {
            $this->db->where_in('dtr_id', $dtr_id);
        }else{
            $this->db->where('dtr_id', $dtr_id);
        }

        $update = array(
                    'total_work_hours' => $this->input->post('total_work_hours'),
                    'time_lates' => $this->input->post('total_lates'),
                    'late_deduction' => $this->input->post('lateDdc_total'),
                    'time_under' => $this->input->post('total_under'),
                    'under_deduction' => $this->input->post('underDdc_total'),
                    'is_ACCapproved' => 1,
                    'is_computed' => 1
                    );
        $this->db->update($this->table_name, $update);
        return $update?true:false;
    }
```

this is my controller looks like

```
if ($this->input->post('bulk_submit3')) 
        {
            $submit = $this->input->post('checked_id');

            if (!empty($submit)) 
            {
                $submit = $this->dtr_model->update3($submit);

                if ($submit) 
                {
                    $data['statusMsg'] = 'Selected DTR Reports have been successfully Submitted.';
                }else{
                    $data['statusMsg'] = 'Some problem occurred, please Call Your IT Administrator.';
                }
            }else{
                $data['statusMsg'] = 'Select at least 1 record to be Submit.';
            }
        }
```

i've search everywhere and still no answer

Comment: What is the issue man?

Comment: just print your query and see it is same the operation you want to do or not.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What are you expecting to happen? What's actually happening (in more details) while `$dtr_id` contains what?

Comment: i want to update the rows in my table ,, with post data in the table ,, but whats happening is that the data in the last row in my table inserts to all the row in my table..

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. You should edit your question to include all relevant code and info.

Comment: im using checkbox on my table to select multiple rows in my table

Answer (score 0):

Try to update this using `set`

```php
public function update3($dtr_id) {   
    if (is_array($dtr_id)) {
        $this->db->where_in('dtr_id', $dtr_id);
    }else{
        $this->db->where('dtr_id', $dtr_id);
    }

    $this->db->set('total_work_hours' , $this->input->post('total_work_hours'));
    $this->db->set('time_lates' , $this->input->post('total_lates'));
    $this->db->set('late_deduction' , $this->input->post('lateDdc_total'));
    $this->db->set('time_under' , $this->input->post('total_under'));
    $this->db->set('under_deduction' , $this->input->post('underDdc_total'));
    $this->db->set('is_ACCapproved', 1);
    $this->db->set('is_computed', 1);
    $this->db->update($this->table_name);

    return $this->db->update($this->table_name);
}
```

You could do in your way too, but you have to pass the third parameter to `update`, which in this case is WHERE.

This is the definition of `update` function, from CI files.

```php
// from: system\database\DB_query_builder.php @ 1821
public function update($table = '', $set = NULL, $where = NULL, $limit = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please in model write below code..

```
 function update_data($table, $data = false, $other= false) {
  if ($other != false) {
        if (array_key_exists('where', $other)) {
            $this->db->where($other['where']);
        }
       if (array_key_exists('where_in', $other)) {
            $this->db->where_in($other['where_in']);
        }
     }
    $this->db->update($table, $data);       
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

from controller please write below code

```
$update = array(
   'total_work_hours' => $this->input->post('total_work_hours'),
        'time_lates' => $this->input->post('total_lates'),
        'late_deduction' => $this->input->post('lateDdc_total'),
        'time_under' => $this->input->post('total_under'),
        'under_deduction' => $this->input->post('underDdc_total'),
        'is_ACCapproved' => 1,
        'is_computed' => 1
        );
 $other=array(
    'where'=>['dtr_id'=>$dtr_id]
  );            

  $this->dtr_model->update_data($table_name,$update,$other);
```

This code wil help you